# Collectible dinosaurs cards game from cereals loot box (probably), in the turn of the 2000's

Tags: identify-this-game

If you're in for a challenge, here is what I remember about this small game I'd like to find more information on :

- It was a small collectible cards game about dinosaurs. Each card was of a square shape, *probably* cut from the cardboard of the cereal boxes it came from. However, it may have come from a different kind of "loot box", something rather common and mostly aimed at children though (hence why it was probably cereals).
- Each card represented a specific dinosaur, or an "era-appropriate" disaster (definitly had an asteroid, maybe volcanoes), each with a single "strength" ranking up to 9 (it think the asteroid was a 9 at least). The back of the cards was mostly red, with maybe the (cereals?) brand written in white.
- I remember the gameplay was surprisingly interesting with such a few things going on, and may or may not involve bluffing, risk taking and carefully balacing your forces. I was however quite young, so take this with a grain of salt. It was a 1-vs-1 game.
- I played it around 1999-2001 most probably, give or take a year.
- It was french, and I have no idea if it was internationalized.

To summarize:
**I'm searching for a french dinosaurs-themed square red cards game cut from the back of cereal boxes around the turn of the 2000's. *Good luck.***

Comment: Do you think that it was a "common deck" game?  A game where everyone draws from the same deck?

Comment: Yes, it probably was